macchanger fails to work after network interface name is changed successfully
My Linux distro is Debian 12.6, 64bit, English and I have installed the package macchanger
The default name of my ethernet interface as assigned by the kernel is enxb7cf11b74274 and the default MAC address is b7:cf:11:b7:42:74
Under normal circumstances I type the below command in a terminal to change/randomize the MAC address:
sudo macchanger -r enxb7cf11b74274

(Why do I randomize the MAC address? I use public WiFi hotspots all the time.)
I find it tedious to type enxb7cf11b74274 each and every time when I wish to change/randomize its MAC address.
So I read up three tutorials on how to change the ethernet interface name to lan. They are:
1.6 Configuring user-defined network interface names by using udev rules
4. Permanent Renaming Network Interface Using udev Rules
Rename the network interfaces on Debian
Based on the above three tutorials I was able to change the ethernet interface name to lan successfully after a reboot.
When I type the command in a terminal:
ip a s

the ethernet interface name displays lan instead of enxb7cf11b74274 with the default MAC address being b7:cf:11:b7:42:74
Then, I type the following command to change its MAC address:
sudo macchanger -r lan

The MAC address isn't changed.
I appreciate your help in this matter.
P.S.: If you look at RedHat's tutorial 1.6.3 Configuring user-defined network interface names by using udev rules, it gives an example of what the file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules looks like. I reproduce below said example with the format:
SUBSYSTEM=="net",ACTION=="add",ATTR{address}=="<MAC_address>",ATTR{type}=="<device_type_id>",NAME="<new_interface_name>"

SUBSYSTEM=="net",ACTION=="add",ATTR{address}=="00:00:5e:00:53:1a",ATTR{type}=="1",NAME="provider0"

Now I am thinking....instead of ATTR{address}=="<MAC_address>"
can I change it to ATTR{UUID}=="Universally Unique Identifier"
so that I can use macchanger to change/randomize the default MAC address without problem.
And because UUIDs are never captured by private WiFi networks and public WiFi hotspots.

What does "brctl show" output?  (I wonder if you are using a bridge, and LAN is the interface of the bridge).   Also, rather then jumping through hoops, why not just write a trivial bash script which executes "sudo macchanger -r enxb7cf11b74274"?

@davidgo Your question "what's the output of brctl? shows that you're an expert on networking. I'm unable to give you the answer because I don't have access to my device right now. But you're right. My device is connected to the router by means of a TP-Link power line adapter. The power line adapter itself has a MAC address as well.
Could you help me with such a script please?
It should contain the following lines:
sudo macchanger -r enxb7cf11b74274
sudo cp /etc/network/misc/home-lan /etc/network/interfaces.d
sudo ifup enxb7cf11b74274

Rereading your post - The problem is unlikely to be a bridge.  You have contradicted your reason for randomizing your MAC address (WiFi != poe) - stop stealing Internet.  My son did something similar on my network recently - I was really pissed off when I needed to move to a default deny and manually enumerate all devices to thwart this - but now he has no internet access at all.

With respect of using udev to change a rule, try it and see. Just back up the old file first so if things don't work you can easily revert back.  Using UUID would seem a reasonable identifier. You might alternatively want to use the vendor and deviceid - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74513/udev-how-do-you-identify-the-physical-device-that-a-sys-device-belongs-to#74585 - use lspci if your inetwork device is internal to your system.

@davidgo You accused me of stealing WiFi. Do you have proof that I am stealing the internet? How is a powerline adapter able to steal WiFi? Which model of TP-Link powerline adapter is able to steal WiFi?

You stated in your post "Why do I randomize the MAC address? ,I use public WiFi hotspots all the time"  - Then your comments talked about " My device is connected to the router by means of a TP-Link power line adapter" - and you go on to provide the same interface name for it. You have a user score of 1 - typical of people making a "throwaway account".  I drew a reasonable inference. On the other hand I also spent time writing the script you asked for...

@davidgo Yes, I did write "I use public WiFi hotspots all the time". But can you pause for a moment to think if there are wall sockets near public WiFi routers to which I can plug in the first of my TP-Link powerline adapters and then run a LAN cable from the powerline adapter to the router and another powerline line adapter plugged into another wall socket and a LAN cable from the latter to my device? Do you think the owners of public WiFi hotspots would allow me to do that?

Yeah, I specifically contemplated  the implausible interplay between WIFI and Powerline adaptors which was the base of my hypothesis that this is not about privacy when you are connecting to hotspots while out and about.   I also considered that once you strip the WIFI overhead, you are dealing with ethernet frames, so if you have an AP Client/Range Extender on the other side of your powerline connector [or conceivably just using powerline and picking a network from a nearby network, but this is less likely].    Why DID you talk about WIFI, then change to referencing  Powerline?

@davidgo I wrote about WiFi and powerline adapters to confuse any potential reader who wish to hack into my system.

Ok.    FYI, none of the things discussed, even if what you said was exactly accurate would make it any easier or harder for anyone to hack into your system.    On this forum we assume that the information provided is correct - save for stuff which is specifically sanitized like replacing a domain name with example.com - and while it did not make a difference here, you may get the wrong answer if you ask about WIFI but mean Powerline as the technologies are different - especially as under Linux there WIFI but not powerline uses wpa_supplicant which could affect the answer.

@davidgo Is Debian 12.6 installed on your laptop/personal computer? If yes, do you use wifi to connect to the internet? (I know it's off-topic here but if your device does have Debian 12.6 installed, I wish to ask a question about the capabilities of wpa_supplicant, especially about WPA3- Personal)

I use boring Ubuntu 24.04 (based on Debian).  Pretty much all variants of Linux use wpa-supplicant.  I don't  know much about wpa3 per-se, but I do know more then the average user about WiFi on Linux having set up a small WISP a long time ago using Linux laptops as WiFi routers.  I do use WiFi on my Linux laptops, and at one time I even made one into a Wireless router and WiFi client in one...

I also don't know how a question about wpa-supplicant would be off topic here. Post a question and see what happens. The absolute worst would be it gets closed. You don't have any reputation to lose and you won't get banned.

@davidgo The title of my post is Are the contents of my wpa_supplicant.conf correct for WPA3-Personal authentication?
I asked the question on January 12, 2024 and up till now, no one has provided answers.

I can't answer that question - but I've given up 100 of my reputation points to put a bounty on it - hopefully that will attract more attention to it and maybe get you an answer.

@davidgo I appreciate your help about sacrificing 100 of your reputation points but you needn't have done so. Could you retrieve your 100 reputation points please? I doubt anyone can answer my question. I have posted the same question in Reddit (Debian) forum, Reddit (Home Networking) forum, Tom's Hardware disccusion forum and there are no answers till now.

Rep points are non recoverable - but I won't miss them.  Its a good question - and its not impossible someone will see it and be motivated to answer as a result.

possible workaround - not answer
(This doesn't fit as a comment). Please read the whole answer before attempting to implement.
To create a script to bypass the need to type a long set of commands is fairly trivial.  Open your favourite text editor (eg nano if you are working at the command line and don't know vi) and create a file with the following:
#! /bin/bash
sudo macchanger -r enxb7cf11b74274 
sudo cp /etc/network/misc/home-lan /etc/network/interfaces.d 
sudo ifup enxb7cf11b74274

Next you make it executable - Assuming you called the above file "newmac"
chmod 755 newmac

There is the question of where you place the script.  The obvious place to create it is in your home directory, so you can access it by typing "~/newmac. To make sure you are creating it in your homedir you can type the following before creating the file -
  cd ~

In a single user system where you want maximum convenience you may want to move the script to /usr/local/bin so you can just type newmac from anywhere to launch it - use the command
  sudo mv newmac /usr/local/bin

Note you want to create the file and set its perms in your home directory first, and then move it because you likely need elevated permissions to create a file in /use/local/bin

David, your script works per my request and for which I can't thank you well enough. I also acknowledge that you spent time and effort on writing the answer. About why my user score is 1. These are my reasons: (1) when my other usual forums don't provide the answers that I need, I come to this forum hoping that some kind guy lik you will be able to help me; (2) my knowledge of Linux is so elementary that I find myself unable to help other users in this forum. By the way, if this was a "throwaway" account, I wouldn't have kept it since 2020.
